# How to set custom font to searchview hint in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am using searchview in xamarin android. I have a custom font in Assets->fonts folder.
I need to apply that font to my searchview hint.

I tried like below:

Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Kokila.ttf"); 
searchView.setTypeface(type);

But its not working. Can anybody tell me how to I apply custom font to searchview hint.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change textview typeface that is inside the searchview.

Use that code to access the textview:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout)SearchView.GetChildAt(0);
LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout)linearLayout1.GetChildAt(2);
LinearLayout linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout)linearLayout2.GetChildAt(1);
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)linearLayout3.GetChildAt(0);
textView.Typeface = YourCustomTypeface;
```

Happy codding!